# How to use tabs in android after depreciation of tab activity? using fragment there is an issue with me

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, tabactivity

How to use tabs in android after depreciation of tab activity? by using sherlock and fragments i am able to do tabing but i want to set tab image as whole not tab icon...
i don't need black bg with my image i want my image on whole tab.
here is my code

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
           // mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);
            mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab8)),
                    FragmentTab.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2",
                            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab9)),
                    FragmentTab.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3",
                            getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    FragmentTab.class, null);
            mTabHost.addTab(
                    mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab4").setIndicator("Tab 4",
                            getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on)),
                    FragmentTab.class, null);

Help Required :)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by using tabhost, you can use tabhost without tabactivity following is the code.

```
final TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

        final TabSpec spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tabbar8, tabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
        spec1.setIndicator(view);
        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
```

where tabbar8 is layout which i want to set on my first tab

Answer (score 0):

You can completely customize the ActionBar tabs by using setCustomView() on the ActionBar.Tab.  You'll define an XML layout for the tab, then set similar to:

```
// Home tab
ActionBar.Tab tabHome = mActionBar.newTab();
tabHome.setText("Home");        
LinearLayout layoutLinear = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tab_standard, null);
TextView title = (TextView)layoutLinear.findViewById(R.id.title);
title.setText(strTabTitle);
tabHome.setCustomView(layoutLinear);
mActionBar.addTab(tabHome);
```

so you can put your ImageView, or set a background drawable, on the linear layout you define (R.layout.layout_tab_standard in this example).

You should also review the Action Bar Style Generator (http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/), you might find this useful.

Comment: You can also call setIcon() on the mActionBar.addTab() method to set a drawable on the tab indicator.